# How can i do form validation in adaptive card

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am developing a bot in SDK v4 using node js. I have a form in a bot and need to validate the fields like email, phone number etc. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can review?